# How to recover cassandra node which is down for 5 days?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a cassandra cluster - 4 nodes (RF=2), on one of the node cassandra service exited for some reason

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your GC_GRACE settings? If it is lower than 5 days, remove the node using `nodetool removenode` (Relevant Docs: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/topo_changes.html#removing-nodes)
 and add a new fresh node after.

If your GC_GRACE settings are bigger than 5 days, restart the node, run a repair on the cluster, and you should be good.

Comment: Okay GC_GRACE is set to default value i.e 10 days
so repair should be run on whole cluster or just that node?

Comment: You should guarantee consistency. So I would run across the full cluster. Either via command line using `nodetool` or if you want to deploy a way of automating your repairs look into http://cassandra-reaper.io/